# Do you need to do consistent read after using a DynamoDB transaction to commit a change?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We need strong consistency (insert where not exists, check conditions etc) to keep things in order a fast moving DynamoDb store, however we do far more reads than writes, and would prefer to sent consistentRead = false because it is faster, more stable (when nodes are down) and (most importantly) less costly.

If we use a Transaction write items collection to commit changes, does this wait for all nodes to propagate before returning? If so, surely you don’t need to use a consistent read to query this… is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Transactional writes work like regular reads in that they are acknowledged when they are written to at least 2 of the 3 nodes in the partition. One of those 2 nodes must be the leader node for the partition. The difference in a transaction is that all of the writes in that transaction have to work or none of them work.

If you do an eventually consistent read after the transaction, there is a 33% chance you will get the one node that was not required for the ack. Now then, if all is healthy that third node probably has the write anyhow.

All that said, if your workload needs a strongly consistent read like you indicate, then do it. Don't play around. There should not be a performance hit for a strong consistent read, but like you pointed out, there is a cost implication.